# Transfer text editor content to another text editor on a separate page

Tags: reactjs, tinymce

Specs:

I need to be able to transfer Rich text editor content from TextEditor1 to TextEditor2. These text editors exist on two separate pages in a React Router Web App. On Page1 the user inputs content to TextEditor1 and presses submit. OnSubmit I need TextEditor2 to be set with the content from TextEditor1.TextEditor2 is for displaying the user input while preserving spacing and format.

Status:

I'm currently able to assign the TextEditor1's content to a variable with  `setEntryArray(editorRef.current.getContent());` but I'm not able access this variable from within my TextEditor2 component. I'm using the TinyMCE text editor.

Outlook:

I was wondering if it is possible to lift the state up from one editor to the next. I'm not sure how you could pass props from one component to the next with TextEditor2 being just a variable assigned to a text editor. The editor components can not be children of the same parent because the editor receiving the content from the other editor would need to be imported into it's page and that is not possible unless it is it's own component as far as I know.

If lifting state isn't possible for this scenario, I know there might be other ways to accomplish this. I'm not familiar with the `useReducer` hook or Redux but I know they serve a similar purpose and might be a potential solution. I just need to figure out how to implement them if they're a better fix. I'm looking for the simplest solution and just trying to find the best direction to go in while also trying to learn in the process.

I've been stuck on this and I really appreciate any ideas! Thank you for your time!

```
 export default function App() {
  const editorRef = useRef();
  const [entryArray, setEntryArray] = React.useState();
  const log = () => {
    if (editorRef.current) {
      setEntryArray(editorRef.current.getContent());
      console.log(entryArray);
    }
  };



let help = null
export let storyEdi = <Editor
    apiKey='your-api-key'
    disabled = {true}
    inline = {false}
    
    init={{
      selector: "#storyEdi",
      height: 500,
      menubar: false,
      placeholder: "Whats on your mind?",
      init_instance_callback : function(editor) {
        if (help == null) {
          editor.setContent("EMPTY ENTRY");
        }
       /* else {
            editor.setContent(entryArray);}*/
      },

      plugins: [
        'advlist', 'autolink', 'lists', 'link', 'image', 'charmap', 'preview',
        'anchor', 'searchreplace', 'visualblocks', 'code', 'fullscreen',
        'insertdatetime', 'media', 'table', 'code', 'help', 'wordcount'
      ],
      toolbar:  'undo redo | blocks | ' +
            'bold italic forecolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
            'alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | ' +
            'removeformat | help',
      content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }'
    }}

    />
```

Comment: Is it possible to have two `Editor` components as children of the same parent? If so, try creating a function and passing it down to one of the editors. Allow the editor to call it (eg a `copy` button) and have the function update the state on the parent comp. Once, this happens, the other editor should update because the parent's state updated which triggers a re-render.

Comment: I know nothing about `TinyMCE` so forgive me if that setup doesn't work.

Comment: The editor components can not be children of the same parent because the editor receiving the content from the other editor would need to be imported into it's page and that is not possible unless it is it's own component. I appreciate your idea though and thank you for your time!

Comment: "...the other editor would need to be imported into it's page..." What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry let me explain better. The text editors will exist on two separate React-Router pages. The first page the user will input content to TextEditor1. When the user hits submit, I need that content to be accessible so that I can set that content into TextEditor2 on it's own separate page.

Comment: Page2 with TextEditor2 is for just displaying the user input. TextEditor2 will be Read only and have the toolbar removed. I want be able to display the content within the text editor so that the format and spacing is preserved. If I displayed them in HTML they would just be plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used TinyMCE editor in one of my react projects

Here's how I had integrated.
And also you can create 2 different Editor inside the same component. If you are wondoring how!, let me show you.

`helper.js`

```js
import { Editor } from "@tinymce/tinymce-react";
  
  const editorInit = {
    height: 300,
    width: "100%",
    menubar: "edit view insert format help",
    toolbar:
      "undo redo | formatselect | " +
      "bold italic forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter ",
    toolbar_sticky: true,
    toolbar_mode: "sliding",
    content_style: "body { font-family:Montserrat; font-size:14px }",
  };

  const getHtmlEditor = (value, setFieldValue, innerRef) => (
    <Editor
      onInit={(evt, editor) => (innerRef.current = editor)}
      initialValue={ value /* Initial data value here */}
      onEditorChange={(e) => {
        /* Set your value here, I have used formik here */
        setFieldValue("formField", e);
      }}
      init={editorInit}
    />
  );
  
  export default getHtmlEditor;
```

Now import this function in your component.
Just make sure you create different Ref for each of the editor.

```js
import getHtmlEditor "..path";
import htmlParser from "html-react-parser";

export default function YourComponent(){
  const [formValue, setFieldValue]=useForm(); // Any form data integration
  
  const editorOneRef=useRef(null); 
  const editorTwoRef=useRef(null); // new ref for each TinyMCE text editor
  
  return (
    <div>
      {getHtmlEditor(formValue, setFieldValue, editorOneRef);}
      {getHtmlEditor(formValue, setFieldValue, editorTwoRef);}
      {/* You can add as many as you want */}
      {/* If you want to display content as HTML with output text (with design), you can also use html-react-parser npm eg. as follow */}
      <div className="someContainerClass" >
        {htmlParser(formValue)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Let me know if this is helpful for you! Thank you.

Comment: @CreativeDesign I've created example in sandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/tinymce-editor-pixjbd , Can you check that! It is giving me no issue!

Comment: Thank you for your response! It was interesting to see your editor setup. The issue is still the same though. I need to be able to export the contents from the Editor1 into Editor2 on another page. editorOneRef contains the contents and that can not be exported. I'm starting think I will need to integrate a  state management library like Redux to make that possible.

Comment: @CreativeDesign Here I have integrated with state management using context API. https://codesandbox.io/s/tinymce-editor-pixjbd?file=/index.js . Let me know if this helps, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes that helps! The Context API seems like an easier solution than Redux. I'm still getting an error when trying to implement your code into my app. The error says "react-dom.development.js:29674 Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element." I'm going need sometime to debug and get it working. I'll get back to you tomorrow once I have more time to review your code and see why I'm getting these errors. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I was able to fix the errors and get your code working within my App. I currently still have both editors on the same page. I keep crashing the page when I attempt to setup the editors on separate pages but I think I need to take more time to understand the Context API and make sure I'm setting everything up right. I feel like I have a good direction to go in now thanks to your help so I'm going accept your answer. Thank you for your time and best wishes!